# Why am I receiving syntax errors when trying to insert line into table in PSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I am trying to add a a line to a table called products in PSQL via Git-Bash and received two separate syntax errors. The exercise states: Add a product to the table with the name of “chair”, price of 44.00, and can_be_returned of false. Here are my attempts: [image]

I am sure I am missing some fundamental concept since this is my 2nd day with SQL/PSQL, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use apostrophe `'` instead of double quote `"`

Comment: please don't over use images, copy and paste of that screen would have been much more useful

Comment: You are missing the `values` clause. Please see the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table has 4 columns

```
id name price can_be_returned
```

but you don't specify which columns you are inserting

Instead try listing the column names you intend to insert